# New LaTeX user trying to install VauCanSon-G (state machine style)

Tags: packages, installing

I'm completely new to LaTeX and I'm trying to draw some state diagrams for an assignment.

So far the options I have found are

```
1- Use VauCanSon-G to generate the diagrams
2- Draw the diagrams in an external application
```

I definitely don't want to need 2 applications to write my assignment, so I must use the style. However, I have only ever install single `.sty` files and moved them to `usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/[stylename]` and use `usepackage{[name]}`.

This style is actually more than one (?) and has a bunch of other types of files listed on the download page. I've tried a couple times and always get errors. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

I have downloaded and install `texlive` (and, thus `tlmgr`). I am sure that my setup is correct because I have been able to use styles I have not explicitly downloaded and install manually. However, when trying to run Herbert's example, I get several errors. I double check if I have the package installed:

```
max@linux-vwzy:~/downloads> tlmgr show vaucanson-g
package:     vaucanson-g
category:    Package
shortdesc:   PSTricks macros for drawing automata
longdesc:    VauCanSon-G is a package that enables the user to draw automata within texts written using LaTeX. The package macros make use of commands of PStricks
installed:   Yes
revision:    15878
cat-version: 0.4
cat-date:    2008-10-30 09:45:25 +0100
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-pstricks
```

So it is installed. Ideas?

Comment: Have you considered the `automata` library from `tikz`?

Comment: I've just downloaded and extracted the `zip` from http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/. Unzipping it yields several directories and several files. Am I to place each file in my latex tree individually? (sorry for the beginner questions)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Don't worry about asking 'beginner questions', the users here are generally very friendly. As far as the location of the style files, it's a good idea to let your distribution handle that as it will get the dependencies correct too; if you're using linux then you should be able to do so using `tlmgr`

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @cmhughes. However, I can't seem to find `tlmgr` for OpenSuse (the source download seems hidden).

Comment: I think you should download [TeXLive](http://tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: As @PeterGrill says, `tlmgr` is included in TeXLive.

Comment: Downloading, thank :) I will update if I have any more issues.

Comment: tlmgr is only included in the TeXLive version from http://tug.org/texlive, but not in the TeXLive from SuSE/Ubuntu/....

Comment: Herbert's example runs fine for me. How did you compile it? I did `xelatex mycode.tex` and `mycode.pdf` was successfully generated. Perhaps you could show us the log. `:)`

Comment: You probably are still using the Ubuntu provided executables. What does the terminal answer to the command `which tex`?

Comment: @egreg `which tex` gives me `/usr/bin/tex`. I'm on OpenSuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save the files of the tarzip from the http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/vaucanson-g.zip and save the files in your home directory: `~/texmf/tex/generic/vaucanson`
Then it should be find by TeX.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}

\begin{document}
\begin{VCPicture}{(0,-2)(5.5,2)}
  \State[p]{(0,0)}{A}
  \State{(2.5,0)}{B}
  \State[r]{(5.5,0)}{C}
  \Initial{A} \Final{C}
  \EdgeL{A}{B}{a} \ArcL{B}{C}{b} \ArcL{C}{B}{b}                                                                                                                        
  \LoopN{A}{a} \LoopS{C}{d}                                                                                                             
\end{VCPicture}                                                                                                                         
\end{document}
```

[image]

run the example with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. A more complicated example can be found here: http://mirror.ctan.org/info/examples/PSTricks_en/33-04-3.ltx:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to reflect my new problem